# Encrypt Data with C# AesCryptoServiceProvider crypted with BouncyCastle AesFastEngine

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle

I need to decrypt Data with Standard C# AesCryptoServiceProvider which was encrypted with Bouncy Castle AesFastEngine on the Java side. (To decrypt the Data using the c# implementation of Bounca Castle is no problem)

Is there a way to do this?

I don't find the IV used in the Bouncy Castle implementation... Is there any?

Any help would be really fine!
Markus

EDIT:

The following code is used to initialize the AesFastEngine:

```
BlockCipher coder = new AESFastEngine();
CFBBlockCipher cfbCipher = new CFBBlockCipher(coder, 8);
StreamCipher streamCipher = new StreamBlockCipher(cfbCipher);
streamCipher.Init(true, keyParameter);
streamCipher.ProcessBytes(data, 0, data.Length, encodedMessageBytes, 0);
```

EDIT:

Hello Grec, thanks for your answer, but it is still not working...
I have a sample solution to download [here](http://www.mahop.net/files/samplecryptoTesterCS.zip).

If you click the two Buttons you get already a different crypted array...???
Decrypting the Array produced with bouncy castle is leading to an exception saying that the crypted data has an invalid length...

Here is the Code I wrote for decryption:

```
AesManagedAlg = new AesManaged();
AesManagedAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
AesManagedAlg.FeedbackSize = 8;
AesManagedAlg.Key = key;
// Use Test
AesManagedAlg.IV = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; 

// Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
ICryptoTransform decryptor = AesManagedAlg.CreateDecryptor(AesManagedAlg.Key, AesManagedAlg.IV);

// Create the streams used for decryption.
msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText);
csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

// Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
var decryptedData = new List<byte>();
var buffer = new byte[1];
while (true) {
    var readedBytes = csDecrypt.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    if(readedBytes == 0) break;
    decryptedData.Add(buffer[0]);
}
ret = decryptedData.ToArray();
```

Edit:

Getting close! RijndaelManaged managed is working but it gives me one byte more of crypted data. All the other bytes are the same... I tryed a lot but I don't know how to get the last byte with bouncy castle... Without this last byte it is not possible to decrypte the data with RijndaelManaged...

Comment: What mode of AES did you use? Just saying you used AesFastEngine is not enough information.

Comment: The following code is used to initializes the AesFastEngine:

IBlockCipher coder = new AesFastEngine();
CfbBlockCipher cfbCipher = new CfbBlockCipher(coder, 8);
IStreamCipher streamCipher = new StreamBlockCipher(cfbCipher);
streamCipher.Init(true, keyParameter);
streamCipher.ProcessBytes(data, 0, data.Length, encodedMessageBytes, 0);

Is this enough information?

Comment: Please, copy and paste code. Never type it.

Answer (score 1):

The IV you are using is the the default IV, all zeros. You should be able to do this in .NET by creating an `AesManaged` object, setting the mode to `CipherMode.CFB` and setting the FeedbackSize to 8. Then use the `CreateEncryptor` method to create an `ICryptoTransform`, and use this in turn to create a `CryptoStream`. [This example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) should help with the last few steps.

**EDIT:**

Looking at the new code you posted, the second line is wrong. You need to specify **CFB** mode, *not* **CBC**. The second line should be

```
AesManagedAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
```

Also, it looks like you are decrypting `readedBytes` bytes of data but only adding `buffer[0]` to the plaintext and ignoring the rest.

**EDIT 2:**

As noted, `AesManaged` cannot be used in CFB mode, but RijndaelManaged can be. Note that the AES algorithm is just the Rijndael algorithm restricted to the 128 bit blocksize and either the 128, 192, or 256 bit key size. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541439/c-sharp-aes-encryption-in-cfb-where-plaintext-length-equals-encrypted-length#9548037) to a similar question for an example.

Comment: Hello Greg, thanks a lot for your quick answers. I will give it a try and post the results...

Comment: Hello Greg, thanks a lot for following this issue even with the timegap from germany to you!!! If I try to set CipherMode.CFB I get the Exception: (tranlated from German) The specified encryption Mode is not valid for this algorithm. ... ??? (The buffer is only 1 byte long - so buffer[0] should be fine)

Comment: Yeah, I get the same error. But it works with RijndaelManaged, which is the same algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for this hint!!! RijndaelManaged managed is working but it gives me one byte more of crypted data. All the other bytes are the same... I tryed a lot but I don't know how to get the last byte with bouncy castle...

Comment: CBF does not work with AesManaged. See exception notes  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.mode.aspx

Comment: @BernieWhite: yeah, we figured that out 18 months ago :)